# construct binary search tree from Post-order traversal in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, postorder

I am implementing code to construct `BST(binary search tree)` from a given `post-order traversal array` following [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850705/construction-of-bst-from-given-postorder-traversal?rq=1). I do not get back the `binary Search Tree` back. I am getting something that makes no-sense. here is my code

```
public class BinaryTreemethods {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
             int[] preOrder = { 5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 6, 9 };
        int[] inOrder = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
        int[] postOrder = {1,4,3,8,6,9,5};

           static int postIndex=postOrder.length-1;
           Node postordertree= buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(postOrder, 0, postOrder.length-1);
           System.out.println("pre order traversal of node from postorder reconstructed tree ");
           printPreOrder(postordertree);

      }
      private static void printPreOrder(Node tree) {
        if (tree != null) {
            System.out.print(" " + tree.data);
            printPreOrder(tree.left);
            printPreOrder(tree.right);
        }

    }
      //this just reconstructs BT from post-order traversal elements
    public static Node buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(int[] post, int start, int end){
        if (postIndex<start || start > end ){
            return null;
        }

        Node root = new Node(post[postIndex]);
        postIndex--;
        if (end == start){
            //System.out.println("called");
            return root;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (i=end;i>=start;i--){
            if (post[i]<root.data)
                break;
        }

        // Use the index of element found in postorder to divide postorder array
        // in two parts. Left subtree and right subtree
            root.right=buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post,i+1, postIndex);
        root.left=buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post,start,i);
             //root.left=buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post,start,i);
        //root.right=buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post,i+1, postIndex);

        return root;
    }
}
```

The output when I print in `pre-order traversal is 5 9 6 8 3 4` which is not correct.

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

EDIT: After swapping the order of lines for `root.right and root.left` (commented out one were before),
the `left tree` is build correctly, but the right tree is not. The output I get is
`5 3 1 4 9 6 8`

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the root of each subtree you are taking `postIndex` which is global for the whole structure. You should take the last element of the subarray (`end`).

It should rather be like this

```
public static Node buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(int[] post, int start, int end)
{
    if (end < start)
        return null;

    Node root = new Node(post[end]);

    if (end == start)
        return root;

    int i;
    for (i = end; i >= start; i--)
        if (post[i] < root.data)
            break;

    root.left = buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post, start, i);
    root.right = buildBinarytreefromPostOrder(post, i + 1, end - 1);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: do you mean use `end` instead of `postIndex` in recursive calls?

Comment: Well, I mean that there is certainly an error there. I think you don't need `postIndex` at all (or I don't understand it's purpose :).

Comment: I added some edit, not sure if that will help you understand why postIndex